# Vb.Net Label always centered

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb.net to make a screen saver.
I want my label where the text shows to always be centered no matter what screen size it is.

is there a way to get the screen resolution of the current monitor?

if i can get that then i can calculate the middle and set my label there.

Comment: Are you using Winforms, WPF, Webforms etc?

Comment: Can you accept answer please.

Comment: How do i do that?, ur answer was perfect

Comment: click the tick next to the answers rating

Answer (score 1):

Stretch the label to the whole width of the form and dock/anchor to left and right side within the label parameters. This will center your label whatever the size of the form.